# ClientAuthError: Token calls are blocked in hidden iframes

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm building a javascript SPA using MSAL.js as a client for Azure Active Directory.

When requesting an access token for my API as such

```
var requestObj = {
  scopes: ["api://MyApi/Access"]
};
msalUserAgent.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj )
```

Msal internally creates itself an iframe to handle the request and then gives the following error about operating inside an iframe being unsupported:

```
ClientAuthError: Token calls are blocked in hidden iframes
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/AuthError.js:26:28)
    at new ClientAuthError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:111:28)
    at Function.ClientAuthError.createBlockTokenRequestsInHiddenIframeError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:192:16)
    at Function.WindowUtils.blockReloadInHiddenIframes (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/utils/WindowUtils.js:206:90)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:474:77)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:472:16)
    at Object.ensureUserLoggedIn (webpack-internal:///./src/services/ActiveDirectoryService.js:93:19)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:36:89)
    at Module../src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1178:1)
```

My Webpage still seems to work as expected but I really not comfortable carrying unresolved errors so I'm trying to get to the cause of the issue.

In trying to resolve this [I have found this issue on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1194)  which looks a lot like my issue.  It confirms that acquireTokenSilent does create an iFrame which redirects back to the main spa application (which then tries to log in and request a token ... so basically an endless recursion). which is why it is blocked.

One of the suggestions is to specify a redirectUri as a page which doesn't have MSAL which I tried, unsuccessfully like this

```
 request = {
      scopes:  ["api://MyApi/Access"],
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/token-landing.html"
    };
    // }
    return msalUserAgent.acquireTokenSilent(request);
```

This hasn't solved the issue and its hard to see if the redirect is even used.  Other suggestions are to check for a '#' in the url everywhere I try and acquire a token which isn't great as '#' is quite common in SPA websites.

Comment: A common solution we have done is to add a check if we are in iframe to the root of the app, and stop the render immediately if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, That seems to work. I wrapped my init code in window.self === window.top
if (window.self === window.top) {
  //don't render if we are in an iframe
  //fixes login loop caused by msal.js creating iframes which redirect back to the app
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
    created: ActiveDirectoryService.ensureUserLoggedIn()
  }).$mount("#app");
}

Comment: I'm still confused as to why the redirectUri didnt work tho..

Comment: The solution - adding a blank html page and using that as the redirectUri -  suggested on [this other issue page](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad/issues/195) worked for me. I am using the popup loginType though.

Comment: is the redirectUri actually called tokenRedirectUrl? and passed in with the main options?  like this snippet ``` const options = {
    loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
    tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html',
}```

Answer (score -3):

Source: https://github.com/lukezirngibl/msal-react-v2

```
enum Scopes {
  OPEN_ID = 'openid',
  CUSTOM_SCOPE = 'api://XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX/all',
  USER_READ = 'User.Read',
}

const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX', // clientId or appId
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',         // redirectUri
    authority: undefined,                         // Optional
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
}

const {
  AuthProvider,   // Use once!
  getAccessToken, // Can use to inject access tokens elsewhere in your app
  msalClient,     // Use elsewhere for msalClient.logout() and other client functions
  graphClient,    // Use for graph client api calls
  useAccount,     // React Hook to give access to account info in child components
} = configureMsal({
  config,                                                // Required
  msalScopes: [Scopes.OPEN_ID, Scopes.CUSTOM_SCOPE],     // Optional (But Recommended)
  graphClientScopes: [                                   // Optional (But Recommended
    Scopes.USER_READ,
  ],
})

const App = () => (
  <AuthProvider
    render={({ state, account }) =>
      state === AuthProviderState.Success ? (
        <div>Logged in as {account.username} </div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading..</div>
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the solutions was? cheers

Comment: why are you posting this? Any specifics here that solve the problem?